# Out of memory error while converting XML to CSV

Tags: xml, perl, csv

I want to convert an XML file into CSV using Anydata-0.12. The XML file is looking like this:

```
<FIXML r="20030618" s="20040109" v="4.4" xr="FIA" xv="1" xmlns="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-4-4">
<Batch>
<MktDataFull RptID="23520135" BizDt="2016-12-09"><Instrmt Sym="OEF" MMY="20171215" MatDt="2017-12-15" CFI="OCASPS" StrkPx="100" StrkMult="1" StrkValu="100" Mult="100" StrkCcy="USD"/><Full Typ="5" Px="5.7367" Ccy="USD" PxDelta="0.5" Dt="2016-12-09"/><Full Typ="D" Px="100.15" Dt="2016-12-09"/></MktDataFull>
<MktDataFull RptID="30818621" BizDt="2016-12-09"><Instrmt Sym="OEF" MMY="20180615" MatDt="2018-06-15" CFI="OCASPS" StrkPx="100" StrkMult="1" StrkValu="100" Mult="100" StrkCcy="USD"/><Full Typ="5" Px="7.3603" Ccy="USD" PxDelta="0.52" Dt="2016-12-09"/><Full Typ="D" Px="100.15" Dt="2016-12-09"/></MktDataFull>
<MktDataFull RptID="31165289" BizDt="2016-12-09"><Instrmt Sym="OEF" MMY="20170317" MatDt="2017-03-17" CFI="OCASPS" StrkPx="101" StrkMult="1" StrkValu="100" Mult="100" StrkCcy="USD"/><Full Typ="5" Px="1.7973" Ccy="USD" PxDelta="0.46" Dt="2016-12-09"/><Full Typ="D" Px="100.15" Dt="2016-12-09"/></MktDataFull>
<MktDataFull RptID="31165443" BizDt="2016-12-09"><Instrmt Sym="OEF" MMY="20170317" MatDt="2017-03-17" CFI="OCASPS" StrkPx="102" StrkMult="1" StrkValu="100" Mult="100" StrkCcy="USD"/><Full Typ="5" Px="1.2775" Ccy="USD" PxDelta="0.35" Dt="2016-12-09"/><Full Typ="D" Px="100.15" Dt="2016-12-09"/></MktDataFull>
<MktDataFull RptID="31165368" BizDt="2016-12-09"><Instrmt Sym="OEF" MMY="20170317" MatDt="2017-03-17" CFI="OCASPS" StrkPx="103" StrkMult="1" StrkValu="100" Mult="100" StrkCcy="USD"/><Full Typ="5" Px="0.8861" Ccy="USD" PxDelta="0.25" Dt="2016-12-09"/><Full Typ="D" Px="100.15" Dt="2016-12-09"/></MktDataFull>
<MktDataFull RptID="31165483" BizDt="2016-12-09"><Instrmt Sym="OEF" MMY="20170317" MatDt="2017-03-17" CFI="OCASPS" StrkPx="104" StrkMult="1" StrkValu="100" Mult="100" StrkCcy="USD"/><Full Typ="5" Px="0.5858" Ccy="USD" PxDelta="0.25" Dt="2016-12-09"/><Full Typ="D" Px="100.15" Dt="2016-12-09"/></MktDataFull>
<MktDataFull RptID="25807539" BizDt="2016-12-09"><Instrmt Sym="OEF" MMY="20170616" MatDt="2017-06-16" CFI="OCASPS" StrkPx="105" StrkMult="1" StrkValu="100" Mult="100" StrkCcy="USD"/><Full Typ="5" Px="1.321" Ccy="USD" PxDelta="0.26" Dt="2016-12-09"/><Full Typ="D" Px="100.15" Dt="2016-12-09"/></MktDataFull>
<MktDataFull RptID="30818579" BizDt="2016-12-09"><Instrmt Sym="OEF" MMY="20180615" MatDt="2018-06-15" CFI="OCASPS" StrkPx="105" StrkMult="1" StrkValu="100" Mult="100" StrkCcy="USD"/><Full Typ="5" Px="4.7838" Ccy="USD" PxDelta="0.4" Dt="2016-12-09"/><Full Typ="D" Px="100.15" Dt="2016-12-09"/></MktDataFull>
<MktDataFull RptID="32444397" BizDt="2016-12-09"><Instrmt Sym="OEF" MMY="20170616" MatDt="2017-06-16" CFI="OCASPS" StrkPx="106" StrkMult="1" StrkValu="100" Mult="100" StrkCcy="USD"/><Full Typ="5" Px="1.0134" Ccy="USD" PxDelta="0.26" Dt="2016-12-09"/><Full Typ="D" Px="100.15" Dt="2016-12-09"/></MktDataFull>
<MktDataFull RptID="32868839" BizDt="2016-12-09"><Instrmt Sym="OEF" MMY="20170120" MatDt="2017-01-20" CFI="OCASPS" StrkPx="107" StrkMult="1" StrkValu="100" Mult="100" StrkCcy="USD"/><Full Typ="5" Px="0.0079" Ccy="USD" PxDelta="0" Dt="2016-12-09"/><Full Typ="D" Px="100.15" Dt="2016-12-09"/></MktDataFull>
<MktDataFull RptID="32444384" BizDt="2016-12-09"><Instrmt Sym="OEF" MMY="20170616" MatDt="2017-06-16" CFI="OCASPS" StrkPx="109" StrkMult="1" StrkValu="100" Mult="100" StrkCcy="USD"/><Full Typ="5" Px="0.4888" Ccy="USD" PxDelta="0.11" Dt="2016-12-09"/><Full Typ="D" Px="100.15" Dt="2016-12-09"/></MktDataFull>
....
....
</Batch>
</FIXML>
```

The CSV file contains parts of the XML. It should have the column headers used in the XML file and look like this:

```
RptID,BizDt,StrkMult,Sym,StrkValu,Mult,MatDt,CFI,StrkCcy,MMY,StrkPx
23520135,2016-12-09,1,OEF,100,100,2017-12-15,OCASPS,USD,20171215,100
30818621,2016-12-09,1,OEF,100,100,2018-06-15,OCASPS,USD,20180615,100
31165289,2016-12-09,1,OEF,100,100,2017-03-17,OCASPS,USD,20170317,101
31165443,2016-12-09,1,OEF,100,100,2017-03-17,OCASPS,USD,20170317,102
31165368,2016-12-09,1,OEF,100,100,2017-03-17,OCASPS,USD,20170317,103
31165483,2016-12-09,1,OEF,100,100,2017-03-17,OCASPS,USD,20170317,104
...
```

I am running this code:

```
use AnyData;
my $input_xml = "oc170120.xml"; #name of the XML file
my $output_csv = "test3.csv"; #name of the output file
$flags->{record_tag} = 'Instrmt';
my $table = adTie( 'XML', $input_xml, 'r', $flags );
....
```

It is working and with a small file for test purposes everything is fine. But after a while I am getting

**Out of Memory!**

as `adtie()` tries to read the entire file into the memory and the XML file has more than 400000 records.

I am using Perl 5.24.1 on a 64bit system.

Comment: What are you doing after creating `$table`? Is it giving *Out of Memory* Error in this line or After creating the table where you are doing operations on data?

Comment: If the XML file is large, you can't load it into memory. Search for streaming processing of XML, i.e. [XML::LibXML::Reader](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML::Reader) or [XML::SAX](http://p3rl.org/XML::SAX). I'm not sure the deprecated AnyData can use either.

Comment: XML::Twig is also great at chunked processing.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. It is giving the Out of Memory Error **while** processing the creation of the table. I am not able to do anything with the data as the program collapses before already...

Comment: That's because it tries to read a lot of data. How big is that file, in bytes?

Comment: Your sample output contains values from the attributes of only the `MktDataFull` and `Instrmt` elements. Do you not want the values from `Full` elements as well?

Comment: Yes, I need them all, but the data from "Full" is needed in another file separately. I think I could really use XML::Twig, but I don't know the syntax to get this done...

Comment: The file is 270 MB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so the problem with XML is that you can realistically assume that in memory, it's about 10x the size as 'on disk'.

So reading the whole thing, and then dumping it out is very memory inefficient, and for larger files - well, as you've see, that's a big problem.

For this sort of task (and to be fair, most XML tasks - I'm a huge fanboy) I like `XML::Twig`, because it lets you use `twig_handlers` to parse a file and discard 'processed' bits as you go - this keeps the memory footprint down.

So for your example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig; 

my @keys = qw ( RptID BizDt Sym StrkValu Mult MatDt CFI StrkCcy MMY StrkPx );


sub process_data {
    my ( $twig, $data ) = @_; 
   # print join ",", map { $data -> get_xpath(".//*[\@$_]",0 )-> text } @keys;

    my %atts = map { %{$_->atts} } $data , $data -> children;
    print join ",", (map { $atts{$_} // '' } @keys),"\n";
    $data -> purge;
}

print join ",", @keys, "\n";
XML::Twig -> new ( twig_handlers => { 'MktDataFull' => \&process_data } ) -> parse (\*DATA);

__DATA__
<FIXML r="20030618" s="20040109" v="4.4" xr="FIA" xv="1" xmlns="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-4-4">
<Batch>
<MktDataFull RptID="23520135" BizDt="2016-12-09"><Instrmt Sym="OEF" MMY="20171215" MatDt="2017-12-15" CFI="OCASPS" StrkPx="100" StrkMult="1" StrkValu="100" Mult="100" StrkCcy="USD"/><Full Typ="5" Px="5.7367" Ccy="USD" PxDelta="0.5" Dt="2016-12-09"/><Full Typ="D" Px="100.15" Dt="2016-12-09"/></MktDataFull>
<MktDataFull RptID="30818621" BizDt="2016-12-09"><Instrmt Sym="OEF" MMY="20180615" MatDt="2018-06-15" CFI="OCASPS" StrkPx="100" StrkMult="1" StrkValu="100" Mult="100" StrkCcy="USD"/><Full Typ="5" Px="7.3603" Ccy="USD" PxDelta="0.52" Dt="2016-12-09"/><Full Typ="D" Px="100.15" Dt="2016-12-09"/></MktDataFull>
<MktDataFull RptID="31165289" BizDt="2016-12-09"><Instrmt Sym="OEF" MMY="20170317" MatDt="2017-03-17" CFI="OCASPS" StrkPx="101" StrkMult="1" StrkValu="100" Mult="100" StrkCcy="USD"/><Full Typ="5" Px="1.7973" Ccy="USD" PxDelta="0.46" Dt="2016-12-09"/><Full Typ="D" Px="100.15" Dt="2016-12-09"/></MktDataFull>
<MktDataFull RptID="31165443" BizDt="2016-12-09"><Instrmt Sym="OEF" MMY="20170317" MatDt="2017-03-17" CFI="OCASPS" StrkPx="102" StrkMult="1" StrkValu="100" Mult="100" StrkCcy="USD"/><Full Typ="5" Px="1.2775" Ccy="USD" PxDelta="0.35" Dt="2016-12-09"/><Full Typ="D" Px="100.15" Dt="2016-12-09"/></MktDataFull>
<MktDataFull RptID="31165368" BizDt="2016-12-09"><Instrmt Sym="OEF" MMY="20170317" MatDt="2017-03-17" CFI="OCASPS" StrkPx="103" StrkMult="1" StrkValu="100" Mult="100" StrkCcy="USD"/><Full Typ="5" Px="0.8861" Ccy="USD" PxDelta="0.25" Dt="2016-12-09"/><Full Typ="D" Px="100.15" Dt="2016-12-09"/></MktDataFull>
<MktDataFull RptID="31165483" BizDt="2016-12-09"><Instrmt Sym="OEF" MMY="20170317" MatDt="2017-03-17" CFI="OCASPS" StrkPx="104" StrkMult="1" StrkValu="100" Mult="100" StrkCcy="USD"/><Full Typ="5" Px="0.5858" Ccy="USD" PxDelta="0.25" Dt="2016-12-09"/><Full Typ="D" Px="100.15" Dt="2016-12-09"/></MktDataFull>
<MktDataFull RptID="25807539" BizDt="2016-12-09"><Instrmt Sym="OEF" MMY="20170616" MatDt="2017-06-16" CFI="OCASPS" StrkPx="105" StrkMult="1" StrkValu="100" Mult="100" StrkCcy="USD"/><Full Typ="5" Px="1.321" Ccy="USD" PxDelta="0.26" Dt="2016-12-09"/><Full Typ="D" Px="100.15" Dt="2016-12-09"/></MktDataFull>
<MktDataFull RptID="30818579" BizDt="2016-12-09"><Instrmt Sym="OEF" MMY="20180615" MatDt="2018-06-15" CFI="OCASPS" StrkPx="105" StrkMult="1" StrkValu="100" Mult="100" StrkCcy="USD"/><Full Typ="5" Px="4.7838" Ccy="USD" PxDelta="0.4" Dt="2016-12-09"/><Full Typ="D" Px="100.15" Dt="2016-12-09"/></MktDataFull>
<MktDataFull RptID="32444397" BizDt="2016-12-09"><Instrmt Sym="OEF" MMY="20170616" MatDt="2017-06-16" CFI="OCASPS" StrkPx="106" StrkMult="1" StrkValu="100" Mult="100" StrkCcy="USD"/><Full Typ="5" Px="1.0134" Ccy="USD" PxDelta="0.26" Dt="2016-12-09"/><Full Typ="D" Px="100.15" Dt="2016-12-09"/></MktDataFull>
<MktDataFull RptID="32868839" BizDt="2016-12-09"><Instrmt Sym="OEF" MMY="20170120" MatDt="2017-01-20" CFI="OCASPS" StrkPx="107" StrkMult="1" StrkValu="100" Mult="100" StrkCcy="USD"/><Full Typ="5" Px="0.0079" Ccy="USD" PxDelta="0" Dt="2016-12-09"/><Full Typ="D" Px="100.15" Dt="2016-12-09"/></MktDataFull>
<MktDataFull RptID="32444384" BizDt="2016-12-09"><Instrmt Sym="OEF" MMY="20170616" MatDt="2017-06-16" CFI="OCASPS" StrkPx="109" StrkMult="1" StrkValu="100" Mult="100" StrkCcy="USD"/><Full Typ="5" Px="0.4888" Ccy="USD" PxDelta="0.11" Dt="2016-12-09"/><Full Typ="D" Px="100.15" Dt="2016-12-09"/></MktDataFull>
</Batch>
</FIXML>
```

Now, you probably want to use:

```
XML::Twig -> new ( ... ) -> parsefile ('your_xml_file');
```

And maybe open a file handle to `print` that output to (at the moment it'll go to `STDOUT`, for illustration purposes)

But the important point in the above is that `purge` call, which tells `XML::Twig` that you're done parsing, and to vacate the 'processed' data from memory.

So should do what you want with a MUCH lower footprint.

Comment: Thanks Sobrique, that's exactly what I need! Problem solved